# Why is My Trigger Doubling Its Effect On A Particular Row In The Target Table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I have a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER Go_System
AFTER INSERT ON Half_Trail
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Accounts
SET Balance = CASE WHEN NEW.Post_Roll_Position IN (3,5,7,9,11,13,15) THEN Balance
                    WHEN NEW.Pre_Roll_Position > NEW.Post_Roll_Position THEN Balance + 200
                    WHEN NEW.Pre_Roll_Position < NEW.Post_Roll_Position THEN Balance
                    END
WHERE Player_id = NEW.Player_id;
```

But it's giving incorrect output for some rows. Specifically, it seems to be doubling the intended value of a particular row.

The initial state of the `Accounts` tables is like so:

**Accounts**

| Player_id | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 290 |
| 2 | 500 |
| 3 | 150 |
| 4 | 250 |

While the `Half_Trail` table starts off empty, but then is imputed as follows:

**Half_Trail**

| Move | Player_id | Pre_Roll_Position | Post_Roll_Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 14 | 1 |

Each input in the Half_Trail table is supposed to cause a change in the corresponding `Player_id` in the `Accounts` table according to the following criteria:

- If the `Post_Roll_Location` is in the set `(3,5,7,9,11,13,15)` then the balance remains the same
- If the `Pre_Roll_Position` value is higher than that of the `Post_Roll_Location`, then the balance increases by `200`
- If the `Pre_Roll_Position` is lower than the `Post_Roll_Location` then the balance remains the same.

As it stands though, when I run the first input in the `Half_Trail`, the added value is double of what I expect it to be. That to say that while the `Accounts` table should be:

| Player_id | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 290 |
| 2 | 500 |
| 3 | **350** |
| 4 | 250 |

Where the value for Player_id 3 is 350. Instead, it is 550.

| Player_id | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 290 |
| 2 | 500 |
| 3 | **550** |
| 4 | 250 |

Could I know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where is your problem, the new position is 1 so it is not in the list, 14 > 1 so it increases 200, which effect do you mean? it is as you waned it, nothing doubled

Comment: @nbk If the update applies it should increase by 200, so 150 + 200 to give `350`. However it gives `550` which means it applied the 200 increase twice (as 150 + 400 = 550)

Comment: no it doesn't see https://dbfiddle.uk/DSstbzsj  maybe your code runs the insert twice, but you would see it in the Half_Trail table if it where so

Comment: Make sure your test case produces the unexpected behavior.  That usually means run the test case.  If you have a runnable test case, post that complete detail, create table, inserts, etc. Always run the test case outside of your program/application.  Often, that process will uncover the misunderstanding.